# Simple tools to format SQL style and customize the format rules?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, styles, format

does anyone know a Simple tool to format SQL style and customize the format rules ?
if it get embedded inside SQL server management studio then it would be great !

P.S: I already use SQL prompt which it didn't have enough adjustable rules.

Comment: Would you be able to include the rules that are missing in SQL Prompt?

Comment: we have a few standard for our team e.g. a gap before each join start , we have our own way of nested function s and nested case statement,...

Answer (score 2):

I have really enjoyed SQL Complete from dbForge (http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/).  There is a free version and it does allow you to set up a custom format profile. It also embeds in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

I use SQLinForm (http://sqlinform.com/), it's fully customizable, but not free.

There's a new Hotkey feature, so embedding should be possible (don't know as I use it on a Mac).